# Non-nullable reference type default parameters in C# 8

Tags: c#, null

I was working to upgrade some code to C# 8.0 and came across an interesting pattern with default parameters and non-nullable reference types. I'm working if it's clear enough to the caller.

Given this pre C# 8.0 code,

```
Task FooAsync(
   Bar bar = null,
   CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    bar = bar ?? new Bar(); // some sensible default
}
```

the `bar` parameter is flagged as one to potentially make nullable (`Bar? bar = null`). This would indicate to the caller that they can pass `null`.

However, if I want to encourage the caller not to pass `null` for the parameter, I could do something like this in C# 8.0:

```
Task FooAsync(
   Bar bar = null!,
   CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    bar ?? = new Bar(); // some sensible default
}
```

Is this a sensible approach to avoid passing `null` into the parameter? I know the caller can still do: `FooAsync(bar: null!)` but that obviously sticks out.

Comment: could someone with high enough rep please create [c#-8.x] and [nullable-reference-types]?

Answer (score 4):

My take on this is that the function signature should not lie.
So if it can handle a null passed in, as it can, it should use

```
Bar? bar = null
```

Another approach could be to overload the function with another which only takes a single parameter. Something like ...

```
Task FooAsync(
   Bar bar,
   CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    ...
}

Task FooAsync(
   CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    return FooAsync(new Bar(), ct);
}
```